# How to extend Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape in Win Store App (8.1)?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, shapes

After several hours of research on how to extend the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape` class, I need to ask you guys if anybody can help me.

Basically I need an ordinary rectangle (since its sealed, I cannot extend the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle` class) and add some members to it. So I need a class which draws a ordinary rectangle with additional members.

Comment: If not extend why not "Wrap it"?

Comment: I considered this approach but I need to draw the class on e.g. a canvas which actually isnt possible with a simple wrapper. If you have an idea how to do this with a wrapper I look forward to it.

Comment: What's the overall goal? Are you trying to accomplish a certain effect? There's likely another way.

Comment: Well, I am developing an editor for directed graphs based on shapes on Windows 8.1 (RT app). At the moment I am moving Rectangles on a canvas. In order to add data to the object on the canvas I want to create my own Shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual answer to the question would be to really extend a class by the `Shape` class (`Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape`).

Nevertheless I found two solutions for my problem where it isnt necessary to use the `Shape` class:

1. extend your class by the `Path` class

   - since `Path` isnt sealed this is possible (see how to draw a custom graphic with this example http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Drawing-bfc39296/)
2. create your custom control based on an ordinary class

   - see this example here how to do this: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-user-and-custom-a8a9505e

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)?

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static Size GetSize(this Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Rectangle rectangle)
    {
        return rectangle.RenderSize;
    }
}

public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle();
        Debug.WriteLine(rectangle.GetSize());
    }
}
```

The Windows Runtime C# projection has a bunch of extensions, e.g., [AsInputStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.windowsruntimestreamextensions.asinputstream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

For a great example of using extensions with Windows Runtime APIs see [this article in the MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn198241.aspx).

Comment: If you can tell me how to extend the ordinary `Rectangle` class with extension methods to have additional members (e.g. for storing associating data) - otherwise you didnt read the question exactly.

Comment: You didn't specify what kind of members you were looking for. There are two kind of class members: [member variables and member functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(object-oriented_programming)).

Comment: -_- However, maybe you should take a look at the `Tag` property. E.g.: `rectangle.Tag = "you can assign any type here"`. So, if you need to associate more than one type, you can create a class that holds all the data you need and assign it to the `Tag`.

Comment: Actually the `Tag` property seems to be the right thing. I'll try it and tell you the result.